# stripe not trying an "immediate" invoice charge upon trial end

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a stripe plan with a very short trial period (10 minutes) where i would expect that after the trial period is over the customer default source card to be charged immediately.

Not seeing this behavior so after examining the "invoice.created" event i noticed that the "next_payment_attempt": parameter was over an hour after the trial period expires.

This makes it very hard to test sub payment flows as well as i would think would allow users to potentially milk services for free for an hour after the trial expires if their card turns out to decline.

Am i missing a parameter i can pass into the subscription create API call that forces an immediate invoice payment after trial ends or is it that stripe just has a one hour minimum next payment attempt for subscription generated invoices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior - the only time an Invoice is immediately charged is when the Subscription is initially created, or when you change Plans to a different period - i.e., daily to monthly.

If you want to immediately pay the invoice, you can definitely do so via an API call: https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_invoice